# LogisticRegression NotImplementedError on fit function

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression

im a newbie in data science or machine learning. i try to implement code from [here](https://github.com/python-engineer/MLfromscratch), but i got error when try to call fit function

here is the code:

```
classification_data = dataset.drop([10], axis=1).values
classification_label = dataset[10].values

class LogisticRegression:
    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, num_iter=100000):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        '''Build a logistic regression classifier from the training set (X, y)'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        # init parameters
        self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
        self.bias = 0

        # gradient descent
        for _ in range(self.num_iter):
            # approximate y with linear combination of weights and x, plus bias
            linear_model = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
            # apply sigmoid function
            y_predicted = self.predict_proba(linear_model)

            # compute gradients
            dw = (1 / n_samples) * np.dot(X.T, (y_predicted - y))
            db = (1 / n_samples) * np.sum(y_predicted - y)
            # update parameters
            self.weights -= self.lr * dw
            self.bias -= self.lr * db
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        '''Predict class probabilities of the input samples X'''
        '''hint: you can put or call your sigmoid function here to predict probablity of input sample X'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X))
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def predict(self, X, threshold=0.5): # default threshold adalah 0.5
        '''Predict class value for X'''
        '''hint: you can use predict_proba function to classify based on given threshold'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        linear_model = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
        y_predicted = self.predict_proba(linear_model)
        y_predicted_cls = [1 if i > threshold else 0 for i in y_predicted]
        return np.array(y_predicted_cls)
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

then i tried to run

```
model = LogisticRegression(lr=0.1, num_iter=300000)
%time model.fit(classification_data, classification_label)
```

but i got error:

```
     31             self.weights -= self.lr * dw
     32             self.bias -= self.lr * db
---> 33             raise NotImplementedError()
     34 
     35     def predict_proba(self, X):

NotImplementedError
```

apparently, it raised the NotImplementedError() on the fit function.

Comment: Looking at the code you've linked, that line which raises the `NotImplementedError` is not present. You can simply remove that line from your code.

Comment: yes after i remove the line, the error is gone, but i wonder, why the predict function only return one class. the result of my prediction is class A for all data

Comment: What is the complete code you are using to predict the class for your data?

Comment: i already wrote the code above. On the function predict. there is y_predicted_cls = [1 if i > threshold else 0 for i in y_predicted]

Comment: Did you train the regressor before trying to predict on your data?

Comment: yes on the fit function

Comment: Are you calling the `predict` function directly or are you also calling the `predict_proba` function?

Comment: yes i use different dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/mrasyidg/pasien-liver#pasien_liver.csv

Comment: i called predict function dirrectly. but on predict function, it calls predict proba

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105547/discussion-between-oxbowerce-and-thenoirlatte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the code. First, you are using a y variable which can take on values of either 1 or 2, which will not work well since the sigmoid function can only output values between 0 or 1. Second, you are using a threshold of 0.5 for the y variable which has values 1 or 2, which will cause everything to be classified as 2.